# Outputting filtered results into an excel readable format without using .linq

Tags: c#, list, export

I have an .dat file that contains a lot of superfluous data (of several thousand lines I only need a few hundred). I currently have a piece of code that is capable of reading it and filtering it. Previously, I was outputting summary data into console with this (which is what the current code does), however I now need to be able to output each individual line that is relevant into an excel readable file. The data contained is in ASCII format.

I'm trying to avoid using linq if possible, because I don't really understand it, and i'm only just about coping with the level of difficulty that comes without using it.

From research, it looks like the most efficient way of doing this is to get C# to read the file, store everything into the memory as a list, and then write that entire list to excel. I'm happy to do the rest manually, once this list is in excel, its just a case of taking the list from c# and dumping it into an excel column. Given that all the data will have fixed length, I'm not hugely restricted in how this is done, but I would prefer it, if possible, to write each variable to a new column, rather than having it all in column A.

Current Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using NsExcel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> myList = new List<string>();

        int i = 1;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.dat"))
        {
            string line;
            var locations = new Dictionary<string, int[]>() {
                {"210", new [] {405, 4, 128, 12, 141, 12, 247, 15, 121, 3}},
                {"310", new [] {321, 4, 112, 12, 125, 12, 230, 15, 105, 3}}, 
                {"410", new [] {477, 4, 112, 12, 125, 12, 360, 15, 105, 3}} 
            };

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {


                var lineStart = line.Substring(0, 3);

                if (lineStart == "210" || lineStart == "310" || lineStart == "410")
                {
                    var currentLocations = locations[lineStart];
                    var letters = line.Substring(currentLocations[0], currentLocations[1]);

                    var tvolume =
                        int.Parse(line.Substring(currentLocations[2], currentLocations[3])) +
                        int.Parse(line.Substring(currentLocations[4], currentLocations[5]));

                    var tprice = long.Parse(line.Substring(currentLocations[6], currentLocations[7]));
                    var mvolume = tprice * tvolume * 0.01 * 0.0000001;
                    var currency = line.Substring(currentLocations[8], currentLocations[9]);


                    // double total = myList.

                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                    Console.WriteLine(lineStart);
                    Console.WriteLine(letters);
                    Console.WriteLine(tvolume * 0.01);
                    Console.WriteLine(tprice * 0.0000001);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0:N}", mvolume);
                    Console.WriteLine(currency + "\n");
                    i = i + 1;
                }

            }

            //Dictionary<string, int> tvolumeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            //Dictionary<string, double> mvolumeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, double>();



            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have one data file, you could just parse the data (like you already have) and write that data into a simple text file and copy-paste contents from that file directly into Excel. I'm not Excel user, but it should automatically put contents from a line into separate columns if you split your data with, e.g., tabs ('\t').

```
// Construct a tab-separated string with your variables:
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
str.Append(i.ToString());
str.Append("\t");
str.Append(lineStart.ToString());
str.Append("\t");
str.Append(letters.ToString());
...

// Push the string into your list:
myList.Add(str.ToString());
...

// Finally, you can write the contents of your list into a text file:
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("output.txt", myList.ToArray());
```

Then, just open the *output.txt* file and copy-paste contents into Excel.

**Edit:** Like ***VoidMain*** pointed out, you could just replace tabs ('/t') with semicolons (';') and save the file as *output.cvs* and then, hopefully, Excel is able to open it as-is.

Comment: Copy / paste is not the best solution here, you can, simply create a csv file or even an XML document and save it as csv or xls depending on the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSV format, this will be much easeier than writing xls or xlsx files (Microsoft Excel Format).
You can write csv files manually or use any ready csv .net libraries such as:

http://knab.ws/blog/index.php?/archives/3-CSV-file-parser-and-writer-in-C-Part-1.html

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use the code he has, but I'm struggling to get the DataTable to create properly. I keep getting a type or namespace name DataTable could not be found error message, I've googled which using I need and tried pretty much all of them to no avail. Any ideas how I can get this pesky thing to create a datatable?